# WooCommerce limit variations per product

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, product-variations

I'm selling hand-painted artwork on a WooCommerce store. Since It's hand-painted artwork,
The product quantity is limited to 1 (Limit purchases to 1 item per order)

I have created product variations for the artwork frame as below :

Variation 1: Wooden Frame (stock qty = 1 in variations)
Variation 2: acrylic Frame (stock qty = 1 in variations)

I want to limit the order to per product/per variations basis.

Example: A User can purchase an artwork with either a wooden or acrylic frame only.

Currently, A user can add to cart artwork with both wooden & acrylic frames.

I don't want a user to purchase a unique hand-made artwork with 2 separate variations.

How can I achieve this ? Is there any function that can be used to limit this?

Comment: Understood your concern. You want from multiple variation only at a time single variation should get purchase.

Comment: @KairavThakar Yes !

Answer (score 1):

Please check below global code:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_add_to_cart_validation', 'allowed_products_variation_in_the_cart', 10, 5 );
function allowed_products_variation_in_the_cart( $passed, $product_id, $quantity, $variation_id, $variations) {
    foreach (WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item_key => $cart_item) {
        if($cart_item['product_id'] == $product_id)
        {   
            wc_add_notice(__('You can\'t add this product.', 'domain'), 'error');
            $passed = false; // don't add the new product to the cart
            // We stop the loop
            break;
        }
        
    }

    return $passed;
}
```

**Also, if you have to make it for some products then you can create a custom field in the product and enable it. Then use that custom code in the front-side and do validate in the cart validation and it will perform with your defined products.**

Please let me know if you find any issues.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I forgot to inform you that I have multiple artworks as variations under one product name followed by another variation as frames. So the above code doesn't fit my need. Your code helped as a good starting point. I have posted an answer below which works perfectly for my need.  Thank you !

Comment: Thanks for sharing positive comment. Appreciated :)

Answer (score 1):

Here is the code that worked for me.

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_add_to_cart_validation', 'woocommerce_custom_add_to_cart_validation', 10, 5 );
function woocommerce_custom_add_to_cart_validation ($passed, $product_id, $quantity, $variation_id, $variations) {
    $variation_id_to_delete = null;
    $is_current_variation = false;
    foreach ( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $item_key => $item ) {
        $product = $item['data'];
        $attributes = $product->get_attributes();
        if($variations['attribute_varient-id'] == $product->get_attribute('varient-id')) { // IMPORTANT = ATTRIBUTE NAMES SHOULD MATCH WITH WC ATTRIBUTES
            $variation_id_to_delete = $item_key;
            $is_current_variation = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    // IF IS_CURRENT_VARIATION_ID : DELETE
    if ($is_current_variation){
        WC()->cart->remove_cart_item($variation_id_to_delete);
    }
    return $passed; 
}
```